# docker run - autokill container already in use?

Tags: docker

I was following [this guide](https://medium.com/better-programming/customize-your-mysql-database-in-docker-723ffd59d8fb) on customizing MySQL databases in Docker, and ran this command multiple times after making tweaks to the mounted sql files:

```
docker run -d -p 3306:3306 --name my-mysql -v /Users/pneedham/dev/docker-testing/sql-scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=supersecret -e MYSQL_DATABASE=company mysql
```

On all subsequent executions of that command, I would see an error like this:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/my-mysql" is already in use by container "9dc103de93b7ad0166bb359645c12d49e0aa4a3f2330b5980e455cec24843663". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

What I'd like to know is whether that docker run command can be modified to auto-kill the previous container (if it exists)? Or if there is a different command that has the same desired result.

If I were to create a shell script to do that for me, I'd first run `docker ps -aqf "name=mysql"` and if there is any output, use that resulting container ID by running `docker rm -f $containerID`. And then run the original command.

Answer (score 0):

`docker run` command has a `--rm` arguments that deletes the container after the run is completed. see the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#clean-up---rm) . So, just change your command to

```
docker run --rm -d -p 3306:3306 --name my-mysql -v /Users/pneedham/dev/docker-testing/sql-scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=supersecret -e MYSQL_DATABASE=company mysql
```

Comment: > after the run is completed.
What determines its completion? I found that in the docs and attempted that, but still ran into the same error message

Comment: the docs say when container exits. it works for me like a charm for a few years already, please double check your use case

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/BnapgHn <- that's how I'm encountering the error - what do I need to change in order to have the container "completed"?

Comment: @PatNeedham you need to stop the container with `docker stop` or `docker kill`